# R lm() working for single row, but not working with for-loop

Tags: r, for-loop, lm, p-value

I am trying to run lm() using for-loop on a matrix of gene expression values. The dataset is divided among humans and chimps, and I am comparing their relative expression. The original data set can be downloaded using [this link](ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/series/GSE45nnn/GSE45263/suppl/GSE45263_gene.expression.measurements.txt.gz). Following are the first 6 rows that I am using in this post,

```
>matrix

                Human_AF_8 Human_EU_11 Human_EU_4 Chimpanzee_4 Chimpanzee_6 Chimpanzee_5
ENSG00000000003  0.1394345 -0.27961627 -0.6147440   -0.1857581   0.19963078    0.4290812
ENSG00000000005 -0.8167632 -0.81676316  0.5223724    2.6947268  -0.59724108   -0.7190366
ENSG00000000419  0.4391277  2.83122842 -0.2066077    0.7903616  -0.26222373   -0.5113423
ENSG00000000457 -1.4025076 -0.07813095 -0.6768202    1.9199726  -0.18687230    1.4537927
ENSG00000000460 -0.8636231 -0.02775471 -1.0507558    0.9997930  -0.01413707   -0.2064266
ENSG00000000938  1.7407105  0.51450595 -0.8887369   -1.1291976  -0.29129441   -0.4344628
```

After reading and converting the data frame to a matrix (the first column becomes row name), I am trying to fit the lm() function and saving its statistical summary to calculate P-value.

**Testing one row works fine**

```
# Making reference
species <- c(rep("human",3), rep("chimp",3))

# Testing for one row works fine
species.lm.sum <- summary(lm(matrix[1, ] ~ species))

# P value
pval <- pf(species.lm.sum$fstatistic[1],
           species.lm.sum$fstatistic[2],
           species.lm.sum$fstatistic[3], 
           lower.tail = FALSE)
# Printing
pval
```

**Testing multiple rows give error**

```
p.values <- c()

for (i in 1:nrow(matrix)) {
  
  stat <- summary(lm(matrix[i, ] ~ species))
  
  pval <- pf(stat$fstatistic[1],
             stat$fstatistic[2],
             stat$fstatistic[3], 
             lower.tail = FALSE)
  
  p.values <- append(p.values, pval) 
}
p.values
```

**Error:** Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels

**Traceback:**

```
6. stop("contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels")
5. `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]])
4. model.matrix.default(mt, mf, contrasts)
3. model.matrix(mt, mf, contrasts)
2. lm(exp.meas.mat[i, ] ~ species)
1. summary(lm(exp.meas.mat[i, ] ~ species))
```

**P.S.** if trying with the [original dataset](ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/series/GSE45nnn/GSE45263/suppl/GSE45263_gene.expression.measurements.txt.gz), change the reference as follows,

```
species <- c(rep("human", 14), rep("chimp", 6))
```

*R markdown chunk*

````
```{r, "LM"}
p.values <- c()

for (i in 1:nrow(data)) {
  stat <- summary(lm(data[i, ] ~ species))
  pval <- pf(stat$fstatistic[1],
             stat$fstatistic[2],
             stat$fstatistic[3], 
             lower.tail=FALSE)
  p.values <- append(p.values, pval) 
}
head(p.values)
```
````

Answer (score 1):

Cannot reproduce your issue. I'm using R version 4.0.3.

```
tmp <- tempfile()
download.file("ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/series/GSE45nnn/GSE45263/suppl/GSE45263_gene.expression.measurements.txt.gz", tmp)
data <- as.matrix(read.table(gzfile(tmp), header=TRUE, row.names=1))
unlink(tmp)

species <- c(rep("human", 14), rep("chimp", 6))
species.lm.sum <- summary(lm(data[1, ] ~ species))
pval <- pf(species.lm.sum$fstatistic[1],
           species.lm.sum$fstatistic[2],
           species.lm.sum$fstatistic[3], 
           lower.tail=FALSE)
pval
#     value 
# 0.7540272 

p.values <- c()

for (i in 1:nrow(data)) {
  stat <- summary(lm(data[i, ] ~ species))
  pval <- pf(stat$fstatistic[1],
             stat$fstatistic[2],
             stat$fstatistic[3], 
             lower.tail=FALSE)
  p.values <- append(p.values, pval) 
}
head(p.values)
#      value      value      value      value      value      value 
# 0.75402720 0.91408640 0.22396503 0.01239904 0.83018858 0.14561322
```

From `rmarkdown`:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I am using the same version. But I am running the code in R markdown chunks. Can you try it with that? I have the added the chunk in the original post.

Comment: @PriyanshSrivastava Works fine, just pasted whole code of my answer into the chunk. Maybe a package clash? Try a fresh R session, without any `library` calls.

Comment: Thanks, it works after I restarted the session. Indeed, it was a library clash.

Comment: @PriyanshSrivastava Great, congrats, glad it works.